# Ordering of properties on an object

Tags: c#, linq, reflection

```
private string DoStuff(object result, StringBuilder returnBuilder)
{
    // get a list of all public properties and order by name 
    // so we can guarentee that the order of the headers and 
    // the results are the same
    foreach (var prop in result.GetType().GetProperties().OrderBy(x => x.Name))
    {
        //    do something cool
    }
}
```

My question is, without the `OrderBy` in the for loop am I guarenteed that the native order of the List will be the order the properties are declared in the object

Comment: May I ask why do you care?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The GetProperties method does not return properties in a particular
>   order, such as alphabetical or declaration order. Your code must not
>   depend on the order in which properties are returned, because that
>   order varies.